# how to extends entity class for xml using jaxb and jersey

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, jersey

i have xml that i need to parse.  i'm trying to extend the class Model and use Polymorphism but its look like the expansion not recognized.

i test my code like this

```
System.out.println((A)(modelResponsList.getModelResponses().get(0).getModel().get(0))).getAttribute().get(0).getValue()
```

and i got exception `java.Lang.ClassCastException` Model can not be cast to A

and when I take off the casting i get syntax error the method getAttribute () is undefined for the type Model

(If I cancel my inheritance. The code works perfectly)

What am I doing wrong?

here is my xml

```
<model-response-list param1="1" param2="2" >
   <model-responses> 
       <model name="xxx"> 
            <attribute> id=1 error="" >val1</attribute>
            <attribute> id=2 error="" >val2</attribute>
            <attribute> id=3 error="exception" ></attribute>
       </model >
       <model name="yyy"> 
            <attribute> id=4 error="" >val4</attribute>
            <attribute> id=5 error="exception" ></attribute>
            <attribute-list>
                  <attribute> id=6 error="" >val6</attribute>
                  <attribute> id=7 error="exception" ></attribute>
            </attribute-list>
       </model >
   </model-responses>
</model-response-list>
```

here is my code

**ModelResponsList.java**

```
@XmlRootElement(name="model-response-list")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ModelResponsList
{
    @XmlAttribute
    private string param1;

    @XmlAttribute
    private string param2;

    @XmlElement(name="model-responses")
    private List<ModelResponses> modelResponses

    //constructor getters and setters
}
```

**ModelResponses.java**

```
@XmlRootElement(name="model-responses")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ModelResponses
{
    @XmlElement(name="model")
    private List<Model> modelResponses;

    //constructor getters and setters
}
```

**Model.java**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlseeAlso({A.class,B.class})
public class Model
{

    @XmlAttribute
    private string name;

    //constructor getters and setters
}
```

**A.java**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name="model")
public class A extends Model
{

    @XmlElement(name="attribute")
    private List<Atrributes> atrributes;

    //constructor getters and setters
}
```

**B.java**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name="model")
public class B extends Model
{

    @XmlElement(name="attribute")
    private List<Atrributes> atrributes;

    @XmlElement(name="attribute-list")
    private AtrributesList atrributesList;

    //constructor getters and setters
}
```

**Atrributes.java**

```
@XmlRootElement(name="atrributes")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ModelResponsList
{
    @XmlAttribute
    private string id;

    @XmlAttribute
    private string error;

    @XmlElement
    private String Value

    //constructor getters and setters
}
```

**Another way to implements this inheritance is welcome**

Comment: Your question has a typing mistake - ModelResponses class name is present in Model.java file. Correct it

Comment: Thank you ... Do you have a direction to give me about  the problem?

Comment: I immediately see a problem if your B.java's root element type is call @XmlRootElement(name="model") and your A.java is @XmlRootElement(name="model"). This would definitely cause a problem and I am surprised it didn't throw an error when initializing. You need to have different RootElement names. If you didn't produce the xml then the person is probably representing them both as the same class rather than breaking them out in A and B. If you merge to one class then A should have the @XmlElement(name="attribute-list") and in the case it is missing it will just be null.

Comment: @ChrisHinshaw  That's what I did but it's ugly and I hate it. There must be a way to implement this inheritance. It should be pretty simple, but I can not do it.

Comment: @ChrisHinshaw i tried to move the @XmlElement(name="model") to Model class and remove it from class A and B but still not luck